# Wrong input shape for temporal 1D convolution in Keras

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, reshape

regarding input shapes – have been using LSTM for a while and didn’t have any problems with it but now I tried 1D convolutional layers for speeding up processing and now I run into trouble – can you see what the problem is with the following? (Dummy data used here)

I get an error for the fitting:

> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_17 to have 2
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (400, 20, 2)

I cannot see what is wrong here?!

Code is shown below

```
#load packages
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, GRU, 
TimeDistributed
from keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Flatten, 
GlobalAveragePooling1D
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils

nfeat, kernel, timeStep, length, fs = 36, 8, 20, 100, 100

#data (dummy)
data = np.random.rand(length*fs,nfeat)
classes = 0*data[:,0]
classes[:int(length/2*fs)] = 1

#make correct input shape (batch, timestep, feature)
X = np.asarray([data[i*timeStep:(i + 1)*timeStep,:] for i in 
range(0,length * fs // timeStep)])
#classes
Y = np.asarray([classes[i*timeStep:(i + 1)*timeStep] for i in 
range(0,length * fs // timeStep)])

#split into training and test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
trainX, testX, trainY, testY = 
train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)

#one-hot-encoding
trainY_OHC = np_utils.to_categorical(trainY)
trainY_OHC.shape, trainX.shape

#set up model with simple 1D convnet
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(8,10,activation=’relu’,input_shape=(timeStep,nfeat)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(3))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10,activation=’tanh’))
model.add(Dense(2,activation=’softmax’))

model.summary()

#compile model
model.compile(loss=’mse’,optimizer=’Adam’ ,metrics=[‘accuracy’])

#train model

 model.fit(trainX,trainY_OHC,epochs=5,batch_size=4,
 validation_split=0.2)
```

Comment: The problem is in the shape of `trainY_OHC`. It is of shape (400, 20, 2), but should be of shape (400, 200) according to your model.

Comment: you mean (400,2), right? That would make sense since every batch needs one tag. In case you mean (400, 200) I don't understand where the 200 stems from...

Comment: Follow-up: It works with (400,2)! 
Changed:


`#splitting matrix 
#data
X = np.asarray([data[i*timeStep:(i + 1)*timeStep,:] for i in range(0,length * fs // timeStep)])
#classes
#Y = np.asarray([classes[i:(i + 1)*timeStep] for i in range(0,length * fs // timeStep)])
Y = classes[::timeStep] `